# XElement.Load native exception in .NET CF Windows CE 5.0

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am working C#.NET CF 3.5 on Windows CE 5.0 , and have another problem.
in my app i load/save some data from/to a XML file as my config by using 'XElement' class.
i have static methods named 'Load' and 'Save' that get a key and a string value to load and save. it works fine. but when i call the my Save method more than 4 times i get a native error. it seems that the previously loaded XElement docs must be disposed or something like that. but how? or what's the matter?
my Save method :

```
private static void Save(string keyName,string Value)
{
    string strConfigFilePath = CheckConfigFileExistence(); // checks file existence and returns only the file name

    XElement xeDoc = XElement.Load(strConfigFilePath); // HERE! throws a native exception at 4th method call! 
    XElement xeAppSettings = xeDoc.Element("appSettings"); // find 'appSettings' section
    XElement xKey = xeAppSettings.Elements("add").Where(el => el.Attribute("key").Value == keyName).FirstOrDefault(); // find the desired key

    xKey.Attribute("value").Value = Value;
    xeDoc.Save(strConfigFilePath);
}
```

Comment: please state the exception message, this could help

Comment: This code does not have an obvious leak. Please post Exception details and maybe CheckConfigFileExistence() as well.

Comment: @Waleed, @Henk , in this version of my app, the 'CheckConfigFileExistence()' method does nothing but concatenating some strings and create a full file path and name. and i can't put the exeption here cause i can't catch the native exceptions by 'try/catch'. i only can say Error code is '0xc0000005' and faulting module is 'mscoree3_5.dll' and it says something about fastAllocatingString...

Comment: does your Save method is called from two threads at the same time, maybe the problem is that the last xeDoc.Save() operation have not been completed, the file is locked for write lock and loading it with XElement.Load would cause that problem, pretty strange behaviour !

Comment: @Waleed, no, it's just one thread. let me tell you the news. i removed 'static' keyword from the 'Save' method declaration and tested some keys again and it worked. i think i must make my code more safer and normal to avoid these unhandlable exceptions. i'm afraid cause i didn't find the problem cause, i just worked around! maybe there will be some more terrible errors later!

Comment: during my code change and enhancement to debug , i found that the problem was not the 'static' mode of my method, it was logging. yes, i logged somethings (save info lines in a file) in my method, but it seems that makes trouble. when i turned off my logging , my native errors like this solved. what's really the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Waleed and Henk Holterman ,
Depend on my experience , the native exception with native error code 0x00000005 occures for some reasons of memory leaks in working with unmanaged codes and native DLLs. i faced same error with in many other points. in my project, i called some native DLL functions writing to input/output parameters like byte[] and *BYTE and etc. i think any fault and indelicacy in writing to memory by unmanaged code and C++ codes causes that exceptions later in irrelevant points in managed code!

hope this be useful.